# Structure and reuse python with Apache Airflow 2.3.4

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have to write some code for an Apache Airflow DAG and I have encountered something that I do not know. I want to reuse some existing code in python 3.x within the Apache Airflow environment.

What I would like to achieve with this question:

- I have my dags folder in /home/'user'/airflow/dags
- I have another repository with code stored in /home/sources. Here I have an **init**.py and a main function which ca be called with parameters and in this repository there are several functions that are called based on the parameters

How can I access **most efficient** the main.py of the code in /home/sources from dag using the PythonOperator?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a conda environment, you can simply add "/home/sources" to the PYTHONPATH.

Let's say your environment name is "airflow":

```
conda activate airflow

conda develop /home/sources
```

---

Now, along with airflow, your python will check everything under "/sources" folder. In your dag files you can simply use:

```
from main import my_functions
```

And give them to Python Operators.

For more information, [check here](https://datacomy.com/python/anaconda/add_folder_to_path/).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have done something similar and for the moment I am happy with the flow of work.

Comment: Sounds great! Happy to hear.